# Vue router 4: remove trailing slash if base provided

Tags: vue.js, vue-router4

Is there any way to get rid of trailing slash (for Vue router 4) if base config provided?

For example:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/my-base'),
    routes,
  });
```

Generates in a browser the following url:

`http://localhost:8080/my-base/`

My question is how to get the same url without trailing slash:

`http://localhost:8080/my-base`

Is it possible?

Comment: [Not possible according to the Vue team](https://github.com/vuejs/router/discussions/1835#discussioncomment-6089014)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Very sad that this can't be adjusted in any way.